# Water in basement from basement door concrete crack

Tags: basement, waterproofing

In my basement I get some water seepage that I believe comes from a crack in the concrete steps/framing underneath the cellar doors.

[Interior 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYju6.jpg)

[Interior 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qrSZ.jpg)

[Exterior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vyKQ.jpg)

On the outside, there is nothing really above it to shelter it from rainfall, there's a gutter but it is not going to catch any rain going over that part of the roof. Everything directly above the basement doors and the little corner exterior spot is uncovered.

I feel like patching up the crack and getting something to divert the water off that part of the ground would help. I would like to know if that is suitable, or what trade deals with this.

Comment: In your 3rd picture it looks like corner of the outside of the basement stairwell and the house is a low spot.  First thing I would do would be to add some soil to that corner to prevent/reduce water from accumulating there, which is what you suggested.  Keeping water away from the house & foundation should always be the first line of attack, IMO.

Comment: Cool - I'm curious how exactly that works, doesn't the water want to just seep right down anyway? Or is it more of a grade or slope of soil that lets gravity do the rest. Should it be piled rather high?

Comment: Yes, if it's enough and it pools up there.  You want to mound the dirt/fill so it slopes away from the corner, what you said in your 2nd sentence.  It also helps if you can find a clay type of soil to put down there.  That wold reduce the amount of seepage.  Usually clay in soil is undesirable, but here it can be used to your advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Broken gutter?**

By the look of the outside wall, more water is landing there than the trivial amount from rain coming down there.  Go out and look during a heavy rain.  I bet the gutter is overflowing.

The whole bare dirt area along the edge of your house looks too low to me.  And why are there no plants?

@SteveSh advice is good: build it up.  You could build it up with dirt from the immediately adjacent lawn which will lower that area and encourage water to move away from the house.  Cut off the sod with a spade then put it back after you get your dirt.   Or fill that area with concrete and put a little shed on it; between basement access and hose is a good place to keep outside tools.

Once built up you could put pavers or square concrete tile along the edge of your house, sloped slightly to encourage water to run off.  That can be a good look too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For now I just think a type of soil to run that off would be helpful, is there a particular type of soil I should use? Should I pack it down a lot? Is there some kind of sealant I can use on that inside wall to patch the hole?

Comment: When in my callow youth I went to great trouble to seal a leaky stone wall, the water came thru a different place in the wall.  Better the devil you know.  Leave the crack, work on the outside and a measure of success will be no water coming thru the crack.  Re the soil; given a choice I would use clay, which is the subsoil in a lot of the US.  Clay is less permeable.  Putting cement steptones on the spot would be easier than digging and you can slope them easily with some rocks underneath on the house side.    But more important: fix the gutter.

Comment: Looking at your image I wonder if water is sluicing laterally off that red sloped stair cover to the left.  You could determine that with the hose.  Easy fix to put a lip on the edge of that.

Comment: Hmm - maybe I should do a water running test. That's actually the basement bulkhead doors!